# Install Mosquitto with websockets in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mosquitto, libwebsockets

I am following [this](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2015/05/18/six-steps-to-install-mosquitto-1-4-2-with-websockets-on-debian-wheezy/) tutorial to set up Mosquitto with libwebsockets in Ubuntu server `(Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64))`at Amazon EC2.

When I try to set up this specific version *(v1.4 supported by Mosquitto)* of Libwebsockets, it says the gzip is corrupted.

```
$ wget http://git.libwebsockets.org/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/snapshot/libwebsockets-1.4-chrome43-firefox-36.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf libwebsockets-1.4-chrome43-firefox-36.tar.gz 


gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

OK, I tried downloading the same (in Windows) and extracting, but it returned an *EOF* error. And I can't find the library from anywhere else.

The new websocket from GitHub is of no use as it ain't supporting Mosquitto. How should I proceed from here? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
I found the files here:
https://libwebsockets.org/git/libwebsockets/tag/?h=v1.4-chrome43-firefox-36

Comment: Thank you so much! This file is clean! :) I think they are trying to obscure the availability of older versions? Or it could  be just me.. Anyways, archiving this file for future use..

Comment: the files at that link seem to be dead now